# How to make recurrent predictions in ML.Net

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, ml.net, onnx

I've ported a RNN model from Matlab via ONNX, to be used in ML.Net. Gru/Lstm layers are supported in ML.Net, and I managed to do a one step prediction via the PredictionEngine and Predict function. My issue is that the hidden state/memory is not kept between predictions.

I've failed to find any alternative functions or attributes that would keep the data between predictions. I've tried to create a TimeSeriesEngine as well, but it seems to only support a single SSA model so this was a dead end as well.

Does ML.Net even support this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.